# what data structure should I use to implement tensor?

Tags: c++, oop, tensor

I thought to implement on c++ the tensor as a one-dimensional dynamic array, filling it recursively, but the problem is in the indices, in order to symmetrize and antisymmetrize the tensor, I need to know the indices.
I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: Why do you need to implement your own tensor? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? Why can't you use one of the many libraries that already exists?

Comment: This is the task given at the university :)
And I nave no idea in choosing a data structure.

Comment: I need to solve this problems: symmetrize and antisymmetrize, convolution, transpose and multiplication

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like telling us what you have tried or what other efforts you made to attempt to solve it, and what problems you have.

Comment: I just want answer for my problem...

Comment: You should probably read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) too.

Comment: Think for a moment about what you're asking for. You're asking for someone to do your homework for you, without you having even attempted to solve it on your own. Why would you think that that is appropriate?

Comment: I'm trying, I have expressed my idea of creating the tensor as a one-dimensional dynamic array. But I am not sure and so I asked a question.